# UNITY. How to disable audio playback notification on WEBGL build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webgl

when the game started in browser on android phone it show a notification with play\pause button because of in-game sounds. Notification bar can be accessed with a swipe down. How to disable it?

Disabled notification bar

Comment: Faced with the same problem, did you manage to solve the problem?